# How to duplicate a object and then save it to local storage

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I have a button in my Project that duplicates a div with some content in it.
Now I want that these duplicates are somehow saved by the localStorage function. So if I refresh the Page they should still be there.

I want to create something like a ToDo list but not exactly. The princip is alike but not the same. Instead of text the user should be able to add code pieces.

Thanks for every helpful answear :)

```
  function Function1() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
      var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
      document.body.appendChild(cln);
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like? What documentation have you looked at and what did you not understand?

Comment: You can't save DOM nodes in local storage. They're references to the structure of a particular page, they don't make any sense on a different page.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to do. Why do you want to save DOM nodes in local storage? What does that mean? Save data, and then rebuild the DOM nodes from it in the new page.

Comment: Save the value of whatever you're duplicating, not the entire DOM node. So on your CodePen you'd save the value of the h2, if you have more values then you convert those values to a json object and save the entire object.

Comment: @RickCalder Okey that sounds understandable and yes I would have multiple values like div objects and text objects etc. in it. But I am sorry, at my current level of understanding of JS I dont know what exactly I should do now o: Could you maybe show me a code example? That would really help me I think.

Comment: @DasOrginal to be honest I am not that strong in vanilla JS, I could do it but it would be hacky I'm sure. There are lots of very good JS people here, maybe reword your question to explain what you'd like to accomplish given this new information. I'm sure someone could answer that. I also suggest being less vague. Give a more clear example of the fields you want to save, if you want to be able to save a bunch of them etc. Good luck!

Comment: @RickCalder Okey, Thank you for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.setItem(‘myStuff’, JSON.stringify(data))`

should do the trick, unless your data is not a JS object for some reason.

fetch it: `const fetchedStuff = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(‘myStuff’))`

Comment: His data is a DOM node, it can't be serialized.

Comment: Well maybe he needs to not do that at all then lol... sounds like a refactor might be helpful here.